# Angular - Get text inside an element from inside an Attribute Directive

Tags: angular

I've created an Angular Attribute Directive, which can be added to a button or link and implement some kind of click tracking. Please see a simplified example here:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTrackClick]'
})
export class TrackClickDirective {
  @Input() trackType = 'ButtonClick';
  @Input() trackName: string;

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.trackClick()
  }

  constructor() { }

  trackClick() {
    if (!this.trackName) {
      return false;
    }
    // Do the tracking...
  }
}
```

I would like the value of `this.trackName` to be the text of the button or link clicked. How do I get this information from the element?

*If possible, I'd like to do this just in the Typescript, and not have to add any more markup to the template.*

Comment: Inject an ElementRef into the constructor: it will be a reference to the button/link being clicked. Of course, I hope you realize that not all buttons/links have text (it could just be an image, or a large piece of HTML).

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, could you provide a full example as an answer so I can mark it as correct (if it works)?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnqaan?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftrack-click.directive.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just inject the `ElementRef` in the directive and get access to the host DOM element.

You can see more about Directives and ElementRef [here](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#write-the-directive-code):

> You use the ElementRef in the directive's constructor to inject a reference to the host DOM element, the element to which you applied the directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTrackClick]'
})
export class TrackClickDirective {
  @Input() trackType = 'ButtonClick';
  @Input() trackName: string;

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.trackClick()
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  trackClick() {
    if (!this.trackName) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log('Element text: ', this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerText);
  }
}
```